# Modrewrite Makes Scripts/CSS not appear due to their path location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues with this modrewrite rule I'm applying.

It works as intended, but when viewing the page, it's expecting an absolute path for all my scripts/css/images. So those won't display unless I go through each one individually and prepend "../" to them (i.e. 'icons/book.gif' => '../icons/book.gif')

Is there a way to fix this with modrewrite itself? Here is the rule I'm applying:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^category/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ fact.php?category=$1
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: This function will determine the absolute path, which is recommended to use for all links on the site.

```
// determines and returns the absolute url path
function absolute_url ($page = "index.php") {
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // remove trailing slashes
    $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');

    // add the page
    $url .= "/" . $page;

    return $url;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^category/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ fact.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

This will avoid rewriting for files present (static files like css, js, images).

Alternatively you can use [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) like this for static files:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/static/" />
```

However it is recommended to always use absolute path for static files.

Comment: For some reason, I tried this and doing something like "http://localhost/mysite/category/animals" the css/scripts don't show up like before, but on "http://localhost/mysite" they show up fine.

Comment: That is bizarre since `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` prevents redirection rules for files in the path. Can you pls tell me absolute path of css/script files and their their include paths on page `localhost/mysite/category/animals`.

Comment: It turns out some pages were using relative paths and others, absolute. I've edited my original post with a function I wrote determine the absolute url path.